# What is wrong with my drag equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, drag

I'm working on the equations of motion for a coupled pendulum. Its still a rough draft. My problem is with the drag force. Is there an instance where the "l" should be squared first? and if so, why? Because once I start cancelling out the ml from the LHS, it affects the drag force so that the "l" is no longer in its equation.

Also, how do I approach Tension T here?

[image: My eqs so far]